# common emitter amplifier output distortion

Tags: amplifier, distortion, common-emitter

why the output of the Amplifier is distorted?

1. the input from the function generator is 1 Vp
2. the amplifier is baised at collector voltage of 4.5 V
3. the frequency of the input signal is 1 khz
4. the cutoff frequency of the input RC is 31.8 hz
5. gain is about 1.2

i should get ~1.2v distortionless output
[image: my circuit]
[image: DC analysis]

Comment: Because the design of your circuit is wrong. R1,R2 too low, Vb too high, RE too high, Q point ?

Comment: what is the effect of the low input impedance here ? Q point is Vc=4.5V and Ic=5ma

Comment: There is no DC path to bias the base, as the tiny dot between base and R1R2 is missing.

Comment: no its connected  i check it again it just does not show in the picture i dont know why  @VladimirCravero

Comment: what does the signal on the base look like....

Comment: Note that the Thevenin voltage for your base bias is ALSO 4.5V, which is a very bad idea. Your transistor is already close to saturation with no input signal. When the base is driven more positive, the transistor saturates, and you in fact end of driving the input signal itself directly through to the output via the B-C junction of the transistor!

Comment: Run a DC simulation and add the results to the question. Also, move the windows around so that your full schematic is visible.

Comment: it is not distorted it looks clean same as the input @Trevor

Comment: @isam I suppose you wanted to achieve impedance matching with  R1||R2=50 ohms = output impedance of function generator?

Comment: No i just feel lazy and i use low value resistor to make a stiff voltage divider  @Keno

Comment: @DaveTweed i think you just get the answer as i remember in a book that i read if you want to use the transistor as amplifier base collector junction must be reverse bias but if the voltages is equal it is still reverse bias am i wrong ?

Comment: Yes, the B-C junction must remain reverse-biased, which is the same thing as saying that you don't want the transistor to saturate. I don't understand the second part of your question.

Comment: I GET IT my second question was when the base voltage equal the collector voltage the junction is still reverse bias ,but i remember that when the input signal is apply the base voltage will rise and the collector will decrease and it will saturate the transistor , Thank you @DaveTweed you save me from headace

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When constructing a low-gain amplifier like this, you need to pay attention to the voltage swing at both the emitter and collector of the transistor.

Let's say that you want to maintain a minimum voltage of 500 mV across the transistor in order to keep it from saturating. This means that the remaining 8.5V of your power supply will be distributed as 4.64V across the collector resistor and 3.86V across the emitter resistor.

This means that the collector can swing at most from 9V - 4.64V = +4.36V (minimum, near saturation) to 9V (maximum, near cutoff). Therefore, you want to set your Q point to close to the middle of this range (about 6.68V) in order to maximize the available signal swing.

This corresponds to an emitter voltage of 1.93V at the Q point, so you should design a bias network that has a Thevenin equivalent voltage of about 2.58V (V<sub>E</sub> + 650 mV).